# Fabric.js Canvas - Make one type of object always stay below the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a project in which I have to add rectangles and add triangles into those rectangles. I get the currently selected rectangle using this

```
const rect = canvas.getActiveObject().aCoords
```

Then I check if the mouse click is in the rectangle and if true I add a triangle.

```
const x = event.pointer.x
const y = event.pointer.y
if (rect.tl.x + 20 < x < rect.br.x - 20 && rect.tl.y + 20 < y < rect.br.y - 20) {
            var points = regularPolygonPoints(3, 10);
            var myPoly = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
                stroke: 'red',
                left: x,
                top: y,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                strokeLineJoin: 'bevil'
            }, false);
            canvas.add(myPoly);
        }
```

The problem is the whenever the rectangle is selected it comes on top of all the added triangles and only after I click away to deselect the rectangle, the triangles appear from beneath.

Please see the images below to better understand

Unselected

[image]

Selected rectangle coming on top of the triangles

[image]

What I want is that even if the rectangle is selected it always stays below the triangles.

Comment: Can you create a working example please (e.g. https://stackblitz.com/, https://codesandbox.io)? (I can't guarantee an answer, but I will try to figure it)

Answer (score 3):

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#preserveObjectStacking

> Indicates whether objects should remain in current stack position when selected. When false objects are brought to top and rendered as part of the selection group

Set your `canvas.preserveObjectStacking` to `true` (it's `false` by default).

It will prevent the selection from bringing objects to the front, but keep in mind that this will rely on the order in which you've added your objects.